# Get host computer information from within R code

Tags: r, windows, server

I want to get host computer information from R code.  For my machine setup program there are slight differences in initial setup of section of the script depending on the machine used, and I need to read this information to know what to do.  For example I have to do something like this:

```
if( isServer() ) {
  resultsDir <- "U:\\Share\\Results\\"
  maxIterations <- 1000
} else {
  resultsDir <- "D:\\Temp\\"
  maxIterations <- 50
}
```

I'm using Win7 locally and the other machine is Win 2008 Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Sys.info`. On my system:

```
Sys.info()
#  sysname                      release                      version                     nodename                      machine                  </snip>
#"Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1"                        "***"                     "x86-64"                  </snip>
```

Comment: Right, and if you do `Sys.info()["release"]` you get "7 x64", so you should be able to use this value in your control structure.

Answer (score 4):

### R get hostname of current computer

```
get_hostname <- function(){ 
    return(as.character(Sys.info()["nodename"])) 
} 
print(get_hostname())   #prints this computer's hostname
```